# two divs side by side third on right side above content

Tags: html, css, css-position

I need to position 3 divs inside a container and I need first div with specific width second next to it to fill remaining space and third which would be on the right side and above second div.

This is what I got so far https://jsfiddle.net/96v5zdra/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">1</div>
    <div class="second">Some lorem ipsum long text</div>
    <div class="third">3</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.first {
    width: 50px; 
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}

.second {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.third {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: 50px; 
    float: right;
}
```

How would such css style look?

[image: Positions]

Comment: what is the width of the third div?

Comment: please add a sample image.

Comment: let's say 40 pixels

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you able to add some code to your question?

Comment: Needs some fine tuning, but could look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/86o3q9r2/

Comment: Thank you for your time but  this is not what I need.

Comment: It does third is transparent and it's border is doted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
  background:#fff;
  border:10px solid #000;
  margin:100px auto 0;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
}

.red {
  height:100%;
  width:30%;
  background:red;
  border-right:10px solid #000;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  /*  the following codes for numbers. deletable.*/
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  font-size:90px;
  font-family:monospace;
  color:#fff;
}

.green {
  heigth:100%;
  width:70%;
  background:green;
  box-sizing:border-box;
   /*  the following codes for numbers. deletable.*/
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  font-size:90px;
  font-family:monospace;
  color:#fff;
}

.green_right{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  background:transparent;
  border:10px dashed #000;
  height:100%;
  width:30%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  /*  the following codes for numbers. deletable.*/
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  font-size:90px;
  font-family:monospace;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red">
    1
  </div>
 <div class="green">
   2
    <div class="green_right">
      3
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way with some bootstrap:

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper row">
        <div class="first">Some<br> lorem <br>ipsum <br>long <br>text</div>
        <div class="second col">Some<br> lorem <br>ipsum <br>long   <br>text</div>
        <div class="third">Some<br> lorem <br>ipsum <br>long <br>text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  border: solid 1px black;
  position:relative;
}

.first { 
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
}

.second {
  background-color: green;
}

.third {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Live example: https://codepen.io/PMertgen/pen/zMyjQd